# 等価演算子にf-stringsを使えない

Tags: python

訳あって実際のデータをのせることができないので仮のデータで説明させてください。

例えば気温(℃)、降水量(mm/h)、県名などのカラムデータがあるcsvを読み込み、それをdfにしたとします。

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', encoding='SHIFT-JIS')
```

そこで降水量(mm/h)の列の中から10(※10mm/hという意味)となっている行データを取り出したかったので

```
data = df[df['降水量(mm/h)'] == 10]
```

としました。実際、データを取り出せることが確認できたので次はinput関数で何mm/hのときの行データを取り出すか決めれるようにしようと考えました。
そこで作成したコードが以下です。

```
RAIN = input('取得したい降水量を入力してください')
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', encoding='SHIFT-JIS')
data = df[df['降水量(mm/h)'] == f'{RAIN}']
```

試しにRAINに10と入力して実行したところ、何故かデータがありませんでした。

恐らくf-stringが等価演算子に対応?できていないことはわかったのですがそれの対処方法を『python 等価演算子 f-string』などで検索しても見つかりませんでした。どのように改善すればよろしいでしょうか。

Comment: おそらく df['降水量(mm/h)']  の dtype は int かと思うので、`df[df['降水量(mm/h)'] == int(RAIN)]` とするのでしょう(input の直後で int に変換しても可)。

Comment: なるほど！！！pythonで型定義はあまりしないためそこに問題がある可能性は全く考えていませんでした...。また確認してみますありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

コメントにある通り、dtypeを変更すれば解決できました。
回答ありがとうございました。